# Economic risk of $n$ items breaking down

Tags: probability, survival, mean, risk

Let's consider a system of $n$ items, where each item has a lifetime $X_i, i=1,\dots,n$ i.i.d. Let's assume that one item is used and replaced whenever it breaks down. Let's also assume that the system is required to work over $T$ unit of time.  If all items break down before $T$ it would cost $c$ per unit time.

I'm trying to associate the description above to a risk. After reviewing the literature, I came up with the following idea :

Let's define $f(t)$ as the PDF and $F(t)$ as the CDF of the sum of $n$ random variables $X_i$. The mean time of breakdown over $T$ would be given by :

$t_{\text{breakdown}} = \int_{0}^{T}(x-s)f(x)dx$

To me, the economic risk $R$ of having $n$ items broke down would be :

$R = c \cdot \int_{0}^{T}(x-s)f(x)dx \cdot F(T)= c \cdot t_{\text{breakdown}} \cdot \mathbb P(S\leq T)$

I'm just not just sure about if I have a redundant term by multiplying by $\mathbb P(S\leq T)$.

Would $R=c \cdot t_{\text{breakdown}}$ be more appropriate as the calculation of $t_{\text{breakdown}}$ already considers some probabilities?